# How to recognize youtube or vimeo site by url?

Tags: php, drupal-6

I have created one form in drupal, where I have 1 field called 'URL'. Now the user of the site will enter the any url here. Now by that user entered url I just want to validate whether it is a proper youtube or vimeo url or not.  Fro example as following:

URL: **www.youtube.com/video_Id**
URL: **www.vimeo.com**

I can easily recognize it by using php function like strstr or preg_match. But suppose anyone enter the URL of his blog which tells about youtube may be as follows-
**www.learnyoutube.com** OR **www.mysite/about_youtube.com** etc.

In the above case my validation will fail because the string of url contains youtube.

So finally I just want to know that what are the valid formats of '**youtube**' and '**vimeo**' videos, So that I can apply the logic accordingly.

If anyone has other idea also, Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are using embed field. If yes, then embed will automatically validate for the proper youtube or video(you have to check for the sites on the configuration page) url. If No, then Pinetree has explained it properly, So use that.

Answer (score 4):

I've been tweaking these regular expressions across multiple projects to match Youtube and Vimeo URLs. They both are great for matching and you can use PHP's `preg_match` to fetch the whole URL or just the video ID. I use it on my projects to grab an ID from a video URL and format a nicer Youtube player than the default embed provides.

```
/**
 * Fetches the ID of a Vimeo video given a URL
 *
 * @param string $source  Vimeo URL
 *
 * @return mixed          A video ID if matched, otherwise false
 */
function video_id_from_vimeo_url($source)
{
    $pattern = "/^(?:(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?vimeo\.com.*\/([\w\-]+))/is";
    $matches = array();
    preg_match($pattern, $source, $matches);
    if (isset($matches[1])) return $matches[1];
    return false;
}

/**
 * Fetches the ID of a YouTube video given a URL
 *
 * @param string $source  YouTube URL
 *
 * @return mixed          A video ID if matched, otherwise false
 */
function video_id_from_youtube_url($source)
{
    $pattern = '/^(?:(?:(?:https?:)?\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu(?:be\.com|\.be))\/(?:watch\?v\=|v\/|embed\/)?([\w\-]+))/is';
    $matches = array();
    preg_match($pattern, $source, $matches);
    if (isset($matches[1])) return $matches[1];
    return false;
}

/**
 * Generate a URL to a YouTube video with a YouTube video ID
 *
 * @param string $id     YouTube video ID
 * @param array $params  Query params to send to video
 *
 * @return string        A YouTube URL
 */
function youtube_video_url_with_id($id, array $params = array())
{
    $query = empty($params) ? '' : '?' . http_build_query($params);
    return esc_url("//youtube.com/embed/{$id}{$query}");
}

/**
 * Generate a URL to a Vimeo video with a Vimeo video ID
 *
 * @param string $id     Vimeo video ID
 * @param array $params  Query params to send to video
 *
 * @return string        A Vimeo URL
 */
function vimeo_video_url_with_id($id, array $params = array())
{
    $defaults = array(
        'color'    => 'ffffff',
        'title'    => 0,
        'byline'   => 0,
        'portrait' => 0,
    );
    $params = array_merge($defaults, $params);

    $query = empty($params) ? '' : '?' . http_build_query($params);
    return "//player.vimeo.com/video/{$id}{$query}";
}
```

Should match all forms of Youtube URLs. Example use:

```
$url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=buNGJm_s0XE";
$id = video_id_from_youtube_url($url); // buNGJm_s0XE

$url = "http://youtu.be/buNGJm_s0XE";
$id = video_id_from_youtube_url($url); // buNGJm_s0XE

$fmt_url = youtube_video_url_with_id($id);
```

Or Vimeo URLs:

```
$id = video_id_from_vimeo_url('https://vimeo.com/ondemand/afilmaboutcoffee/112360104'); // 112360104
$id = video_id_from_vimeo_url('https://vimeo.com/112360104'); // 112360104
```

I use a combination of these functions and the regular expressions to match the correct formatter and then output a nice video. In my recent Ember app, I have a Javascript component that observes the URL change and then updates an HTML output to show the preview of the video. Uses the same RegEx as the PHP version. Something like this (coffeescript):

```
  YOUTUBE_EXPR = /^(?:(?:(?:https?:)?\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu(?:be\.com|\.be))\/(?:watch\?v\=|v\/|embed\/)?([\w\-]+))/i
  VIMEO_EXPR   = /^(?:(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?vimeo\.com.*\/([\w\-]+))/i
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just match the domain part **at the beginning** of the url

```
preg_match('#^((http://)|(https://)){0,1}(www\.){0,1}youtube\.com#', $url)
```

This is how this preg works:

```
^ - everything after this should be at the very beginning
( - start sub pattern which can be "http://" or "https://"
   (http://)
   | - OR       
   (https://)
) - end subpattern 
{0,1} - look for 0 to 1 occurrences of the previous subpattern
(www\.){0,1} - look for 0 to 1 occurrences of "www."
youtube\.com - look for "youtube.com"
```

And it will match anything starting with:

```
http(s)://www.youtube.com
http(s)://youtube.com
www.youtube.com
youtube.com
```

EDIT: JavaScript version:

```
var site= 'http://www.youtube.com';
var match = site.match(/^((http:\/\/)|(https:\/\/)){0,1}(www\.){0,1}youtube\.com/);
```

`match` will have an array of matched values if the string matches or `null` if not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But what about if user enters url without http or www.

Comment: Thanks for the description. I will check it.

Comment: I think you can use anything as a delimiter. The standard is "/" but then you'd have to escape the slashes, so not using "/" here makes it a bit more readable

Comment: Check the edit. Please accept the answer if it helped you with your question.